# Rename Virtual Machine Managed Disks on Microsoft Azure through PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell, azure-disk

How to Rename Virtual Machine Managed Disks on Microsoft Azure through PowerShell?

I tried with,

```
Update-AzureRmDisk
```

But I'm not able to change the name,

How can I do that?

Comment: This is not possible.  There is a feedback item for this functionality here https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/10765368-changing-disk-name-of-virtual-machine.

Comment: @RickRainey sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no command the change the managed disk directly. So you cannot do that with one command.

But there is always another way to achieve that. And the solution follow five steps below:

1. Determine the Virtual Machine ARM template
2. Delete the Virtual Machine
3. Copy disks with new names
4. Re-create the Virtual Machine and attach to disk copies
5. Delete original disks

The solution we lay out here is based on ARM template.  You could accomplish something similar using PowerShell or Command Line Interface (CLI) scripts. For more details, see [Renaming Virtual Machine Disks](https://vincentlauzon.com/2017/10/17/renaming-virtual-machine-disks/).